# Magento Coupon code doesn't work as it shoud?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

So, I have this coupon code **`MYFIRSTORDER`** which is based on the following

**1. for "New Customers" that sign up**

**2. Spend a minimum of £20**

to get a £5 off their first order. The below image depicts the relevant settings in magento admin panel. Now, the coupon validates if the customer has logged in and the sub-total is £20. (which is perfect).

However, if a customer adds products worth £20 and then removes some / all items bringing the sub-total below £20, Magento doesn't remove the coupon code (as the conditions are not being met) and still honours it.

Is this a bug? Shouldn't magento remove the coupon code automatically?

[image: stackoverflow coupon]

Comment: which magento version you are using? Can you please provide your front end screen shot?

Comment: @Akhilesh v.1.9.2.1

Comment: @AkhileshPatel If you're wondering that because the UI looks different, it is because I've used a theme for the admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You're correct. The coupon code is automatically removed when the conditions are not met.

One thing i want to point out is you do not need to specify `> 20` in the textbox next to `equals or greater than`. You just need to specify your condition like this :

```
Subtotal  equals or greater than  20
```

When you specify the condition `> 20` , the coupon code will not be automatically removed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ohh..How could I have missed that? Actually I remember not being able to understand that i had to click the ellipsis (three dots) to add a condition rather than adding a conditional operator. And then, I figured it out. In the process, I forgot to remove the **">"**